# Get multiple street address from a Google Map reverse geocode api call

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I have a client that would like a list of possible street address matches to show up in an app.

I am already using Google maps reverse geo-coding to retrieve the street address for the given latitude and longitude.

Is there a way to tell Google maps to give all nearby street address?  i.e. "All street addresses within 1/2 mile of the given latitude and longitude"

Comment: Google does not provide an easy way to search for *nearby streets*. Maybe have a look at other APIs such as OSM, Bing, etc. I can see that GeoNames has a [find nearby streets](http://www.geonames.org/maps/osm-reverse-geocoder.html) service.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is using Autocomplete with search-area boundaries: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area, although it's probably not exactly what you're asking for.